# In the following problem, where did $v_{cm}$ come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, spring

In the following problem, where did [image] come from? I don't recall any formula that this equation could be derived from...?

[image]

Comment: Um: it came from conservation of momentum: did you read the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inelastic scattering, the initial momentum is $m_b v_{b_i}$. After collision, both $m_b$ and $m_c$ move together, with a velocity $v_{b_f}=v_{c_f}=v_{cm}$. By conservation of momentum $m_b v_{b_i}=m_b v_{b_f}+m_c v_{c_f}=(m_b +m_c)v_{cm}$, whichyield the equation that you are looking for